# Is the avatar a copy of a god or the god himself?

Tags: rebirth

When the god (like Shiva or Vishnu) is incarnated on earth, this means that He seize to exist in his Loka at the same time?, i.e: Is the avatar a copy of a god or the god himself?

Comment: It isn't a copy it more of an expansion: the deva therefore still exists. For example Rama met Vishnu at one time.